# Sequence of continuous complex functions that converge to a discontinuous complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone please share a couple of examples of a sequence of complex (not real) continuous functions that converge to a non-continuous complex function?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to convert a real sequence to a  complex, non-real example you could multiply it by $i$.

Comment: Is there a domain requirement? How about $z^n$ on the closed unit disc?

Comment: @dbx $z^n$ satisfies the question in the body of the post but not the one in the title. It doesn't converge pointwise on the closed unit disc. For example, at $z=-1$, $(-1)^n$ is non-constant periodic.

Comment: @David Note that 'converge to a discontinuous complex function' and 'do not converge to a continuous complex function' are two different properties.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzgy Thanks, I edited my request.